# Black screen under Linux (Fedora 16)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, linux

Launch:

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
```

Exception after login:

```
Exception in thread "Minecraft main thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/fabianhjr/.minecraft/bin/natives/liblwjgl.so: /home/fabianhjr/.minecraft/bin/natives/liblwjgl.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1928)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:69)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:65)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:81)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:98)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:180)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:648)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/java/jre/lib/amd64"
java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame
```

http://paste2.org/p/1849276

I am using openJDK 1.7.0, 64 under Fedora 16.

Comment: Can we please get some more information about your system? Especially architecture and installed Fedora-Version (32 or 64-bit?). This looks like a problem between 32 and 64-bit, like your OS is 64bit but installed java 32bit, or vice versa or similar.

Comment: F16(64 Bit), openjdk-1.7.0* for x86_64

Comment: AFAIK openJDK is not supported by minecraft. Try with Sun's JDK.

Comment: It could be that something went wrong while updating, you could try to get the lates lwjgl binaries yourself for your architecture and try with those.

Comment: Not really to do with the question, but are you the LinuxOutlaws Fab? Given the confluence of Linux and Minecraft, it seems likely :D

Comment: Nope, but thanks for mentioning it. My Fedora laptop is mainly for "production" while I normally use Win7 at home for games.

Comment: It looks like OpenJDK was the problem and installing Java solved it. @Maerlyn please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenJDK is not supported by Minecraft. Install Sun's JDK.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, a workaround to continue using OpenJDK is to copy the 64bit native libraries over their 32 bit counterparts, as the issue here is that it is loading the 32bit versions when it expects the 64bit version.

i.e. Copy every whatever64.so in your bin/natives folder over the whatever.so file. However, you will need to do this every update.

[You may also need to download the latest LWJGL, depending on your Java version](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php/topic,4085.msg22080.html#msg22080)